# interfacing with raspberry pi gpio

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, gpio

I need some help. I am trying to write java code to work on a pi to check the status of a pin in the gpio. Please help. I keep seeing different codes that aren't working. I downloaded pi4j and its still not working.

Comment: Please add more detail (i.e. code) to your question, showing what you are trying, and in what way it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can get various libraries for this, but I think it should be possible, and relatively straightforward, to interact with the GPIO using ordinary Java file read/write operations. For example, to use (say) pin 2 as an input, you would need to write the string "2" to `/sys/class/gpio/export`, then write "in" to `/sys/class/gpio/gpio2/direction`. Then you can read the pin state from `/sys/class/gpio/gpio2/value`.

I have to confess that I've never tried this in Java, only C, but I can't see why it wouldn't work the same.

I guess this doesn't amount to a full answer, but this is the only bit that's specific to the GPIO. The rest is ordinary Java file handling stuff. However, if you want to do more sophisticated stuff like de-bouncing switch contacts, you might be better off finding a library, where that rather irksome stuff has already been done.